# Is it possible to create an IntelliJ plugin to create a new "Module Type"

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is it possible to create an IntelliJ plugin to create a new "Module Type"?

I want to create a new module type in a project that can be dependent on other modules of any type in the project, and be a dependency for any other modules in the project, and when building the new custom module type execute code specific to the new type of module (i.e.: its custom compiler or other external command or process).

Answer (score 2):

Check [IntelliJ IDEA Community Source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community), for example Android plug-in adds a new module type.

Right now there is a major API redesign in progress for IDEA 12 in order to provide templates for modules and projects. See [this directory](http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/android.git;a=tree;f=android/src/org/jetbrains/android/newProject) for Android templates.

Comment: Thanks - Hopefully this will all move toward a plugin SDK ( like ones I have created for other products ) with sample buildable stripped down "hello world" plugin shell projects that are buildable and deployable and descriptions of how the APIs operate :)

Comment: Note my intention is to create a plugin that will allow me to create a "module" that can invoke a script ( Ruby, makefile, or whatever ) to build/clean/rebuild it's output.  And to supply the module's script with the global, project, and module defined variables and paths.  And to be able to make that module dependent on other modules, and other modules dependent on it.  That is unless you have one that will do this already :):)

Comment: I just spent 3 days looking at this and it seems to manage to create a plugin to execute a "shell command" for each of the cases of "build", "rebuild" and "clean" and make it dependent on other libraries, and modules and be a dependency of other modules is no simple matter and there are very few docs or examples to guide one in this endeavor.